# jquery append() function not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating my own custom chat bar all the related coding i have done, database and all the php functions working fine but when after submit the chat input message i am trying to append the input box data with jquery append function its not working at all.

html:

```
    <div class="chat-bar-wrapper">
        <div class="chat-bar-head">
            <div class="chat-bar-icons-top">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-bar-title">
                <p>Chat Online</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-bar-form">
            <div class="chat-bar-text-display" id="messages_output"></div>
            <form class="message-box" id="chat-form">
                <div class="chat-bar-text-inputs">
                    <div class="chat-bar-text-input">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="messages_input" placeholder="Enter your text here">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="chat-bar-text-enter">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning form-control" value="@">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){

$("#messages_output").load('ChatMsgLoad.php');

    $("#chat-form").submit(function(){

        $.post('chatMsgPost.php', $('#chat-form').serialize(), function(data){
            $('#messages_output').append(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is in `data`? Try to use `data.text`

Comment: How does `data` return?

Comment: What will return in 'data' ?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the return value from chatMsgPost.php file?

Comment: Check your JavaScript console for errors. Check that the function you are passing to `post()` is being called. Check that `data` is the value you expect. Check that `$('#messages_output')` finds an element (by testing its `length`).

Comment: Use the command console.log(data); before the append to see what is in data. Then use firebug or chrome developer tools to see what prints in the console. Another option to test is to change append(data) to append('Is this writing?') to see if append is working.

Comment: hi, i have checked append is working but with data its printing nothing in console by doing console.log(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this appendTo() instead of append().

```
$( data ).appendTo( "#messages_output");
```

And check in the console whether *data* variable contains something.
Read more here [appendTo() in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

Comment: can you also suggest how to add callback to it?